# window.open function load CSS

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to load CSS during pop up a window?

```
       function kmt_ShowBoxPopup(targetDivID, aTag)
        {
        var orgin_div_content=document.getElementById(targetDivID).innerHTML;
        //alert(targetDivID);
        showBoxPopupWin =window.open("",targetDivID,'height=400,width=710,screenX=250,screenY=80, scrollbars=yes');
        showBoxPopupWin.document.write ('<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">'+
'<html><head><title>'+targetDivID+'</title></head><body>'+orgin_div_content+'</body</html>');
        if (window.focus) {showBoxPopupWin.focus()}
        }


    <a class="cs_popuplink" onclick="kmt_ShowBoxPopup('BOX02_01',this); return false; ">show me how..</a>


 <div id = "BOX02_01" STYLE=display:none>
    p
    p
    p
    </div>
```

Here is my code. I would like to load a CSS in showBoxPopupwin.document.write function. Is it possible?

cheers,
Qing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just write a `<link href="your.css" ... />` just like you're writing the rest of the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `link` element before `</head>` just as you would in any other HTML document.

Comment: Thanks, follow up question, i can also load javascript as well. Right?

Comment: It's a HTML document. You can do everything you can do in a normal HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just output a normal `link` tag in the HTML you're writing.